# DependencyFailedException when trying to run lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, raspberry-pi3, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to make a face recognizing robot using this tutorial: https://github.com/just4give/raspi-dexter-lex-ai

I have looked up the following reasons I may be getting the error: DependencyFailedException code 424. It seems there are quite a few reasons it may be failing.

```
DependencyFailedException
One of the dependencies, such as AWS Lambda or Amazon Polly, threw an exception. For example,

If Amazon Lex does not have sufficient permissions to call a Lambda function.

If a Lambda function takes longer than 30 seconds to execute.

If a fulfillment Lambda function returns a Delegate dialog action without removing any slot values.

HTTP Status Code: 424
```

I have forwarded the port on my pi and made it accessible using dataplicity. Here is a picture of my environment variable: https://gyazo.com/47d1640c681ebb2a87a216c71817f9e9

And here is a picture of the permissions I have given to the lambda function:
https://gyazo.com/ca7082a8580904cf77b32e3f0ca07518

I cant seem to understand why there would be a permission error or a time out error as I have also increased the timeout on the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Daveyman123